# Submit many to many association to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gallery, Category are generated with scaffold and I did not make any changes in the controllers they have a has_and_belongs_to_many association and the join table exists.The Category already exists and I want to add it to a gallery that I am creating with the form where the code below is from.

The dropdown menu displays all the Categories in the database.I want to submit the data to the database, that is to say I want a new entry in the join table that contains both ids while creating a new gallery

Here is my form:

```
#_form.html.erb (For Galleries)
<div class="dropdown">
  <%= f.label "Choose Category" %>
  <%= f.select :id, Category.all.map{|g,v| [g.name,g.id]}, :class => 'dropdown-menu' %> </div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what changes in my controllers I have to make in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. I think it explains things very good.

I guess it should be something like:

```
category = Category.find_by(name: params[:name])
category.galleries.build(attributes)
```

Comment: I've checked out the link before but it didnt help me at all. Category has :name (string) only and i want to add that to the Gallery I am creating. In which controller do i have to add that ? would it be @category.galleries.build(name) in my galleries_controller ?

Comment: I would guess yes, in your galleries_controller.

Comment: By the way. Do you really want the has_and_belongs_to_many association? It sound like you would want:
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
end
 
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gallery
end

Comment: I've added your code but i'm getting a noMethodError in galleriescontroller#new /galleriescontroller#create when i'm accessing that page

I want to add multiple categories to my gallery(it's just short for gallerypost) and each category can have multiple posts referring to it. So I think yes

Comment: Do you see which method it cannot find?

Comment: undefined method `galleries` for nil:NilClass

Comment: So category is nil.. The Catergory.find_by(name: params[:name]) was just a guess. What params do you have? I'm also new to rails and I'm not so familiar with form. params[:name] should be something else. Perhaps something link adding name="category" to the form and then params[:category].

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to help what i understand you need to save a id to another table right?

```
<%= f.select :ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all.sort_by(&:name), :id, :name, f.object._ids), {}, include_blank: true, multiple: true%>
```

params for controller

```
params.require(:sampletable).permit(:name, :ids => [])
```

if i am wrong please correct me i want to help you thanks

Comment: I had to change :ids to :id and f.object._ids to f.object_id in order to acces the page without an error. 

I am trying to save the ID from my gallery i am creating and the ID from a category that is chosen in that form in my join table that i created with the has_and_belongs_to_many association

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution thanks to a step by step guide.

categories_controller:

```
@galleries = Gallery.all
#had to add that to edit & new

#category_params
params.require(:category).permit(:name, :gallery_ids =>[])
```

gallery_controller:

```
#new,edit
@categories = Category.all    

#category_params
params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :image, :description, :category_ids =>[])
```

categories views:

```
#_form.html.erb
<div class="field">
<%= collection_check_boxes(:category, :gallery_ids, @galleries, :id, :title) %>
</div>

#index.html.erb
<p><%= category.galleries.map {|g| g.title}.join(', ') %></p>

#show.html.erb
<%= @category.galleries.map {|g| g.title}.join(', ') %>
```

gallery views:

```
#_form.html.erb
<%= collection_check_boxes(:gallery, :category_ids, @categories, :id, :name) %>

#index.html.erb
<p><%= gallery.categories.map {|c| c.name}.join(', ') %></p>

#show.html.erb
<%= @gallery.categories.map {|c| c.name}.join(', ') %>
```

And it's working now.